# Ajax XHR failed loading with Internal Server error 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, synology

Would appreciate help.  Have checked other posts similar to this title, but not specific enough.

I am trying to implement an ajax invoke of a php script on a Synology DS415play running DSM 6.2.3-25426 Update 2.  I am following the guidance given here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery, using three files: index.html, form.js and process.php

However, the ajax call in form.js is failing with the following console messages:

```
   VM322:1 POST http://192.168.7.20/~user/process.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

   VM322:1 XHR failed loading: POST "http://192.168.7.20/~user/process.php"
```

The network log shows the following:

```
Request URL: http://192.168.7.20/~user/process.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 192.168.7.20:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

**Response Headers**
    Accept-Ranges: bytes
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Encoding: gzip
    Content-Length: 1696
    Content-Type: text/html
    Date: Wed, 04 Nov 2020 23:44:21 GMT
    ETag: "cfa-5ae3c755f3d80"
    Keep-Alive: timeout=20
    Last-Modified: Tue, 01 Sep 2020 08:39:34 GMT
    Server: nginx
    Vary: Accept-Encoding

**Request Headers**
    Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Connection: keep-alive
    Content-Length: 5
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
    Cookie: stay_login=0; id=c6OiV4GQDLu86y7E3yfyJTNHdambIB1thxRyeiDnDjgBrXSdBh25Lw2pbbJDQo1WGppdrfrFrm208MiUZ0HfCw; smid=WFXk4Mx31ghEHii0PVWGAsbNsHnd3uBl-toxQM3_VofCuY-KKq5EdnvNq6V7PojMcNxbWVUwQ78s7DKHui-2rA
    DNT: 1
    Host: 192.168.7.20
    Origin: http://192.168.7.20
    Pragma: no-cache
    Referer: http://192.168.7.20/~user/
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
```

The three source files are here (all stored in the user/www folder):

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>    
<html>    
<head>    
    <title>Look I'm AJAXing!</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap via CDN -->    
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- load jquery via CDN -->    
    <script src="form.js"></script> <!-- load our javascript file -->    
</head>

<body>    
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">    
    <h1>Processing an AJAX Form</h1>    
    <!-- OUR FORM -->    
    <form action="process.php" method="POST">    
        <!-- NAME -->    
        <div id="name-group" class="form-group">    
            <label for="name">Name</label>    
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Henry Pym">    
            <!-- errors will go here -->    
        </div>    
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>    
    </form>    
</div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

**form.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    // process the form    
    $('form').submit(function(event) {    
        // get the form data    
        var formData = {    
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val()    
        };    
        // process the form    
        $.ajax({    
            type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)    
            url         : 'process.php', // the url where we want to POST    
            data        : formData, // our data object    
            dataType    : 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server    
            encode      : true    
        })    
            // using the done promise callback    
            .done(function(data) {    
                // here we will handle errors and validation messages    
                if ( ! data.success) {    
                  // handle errors for name ---------------    
                  if (data.errors.name) {    
                    $('#name-group').addClass('has-error'); // add the error class to show red input    
                    $('#name-group').append('<div class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</div>'); // add the actual error message under our input    
                  }    
                   } else {    
                   // ALL GOOD! just show the success message!    
                      $('form').html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');    
                   }    
           }) 
          // using the fail promise callback    
          .fail(function(data) {    
             //Server failed to respond - Show an error message    
               $('form').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">Could not reach server, please try again later.</div>');    
    });    
        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page    
        event.preventDefault();    
    });   

});
```

**process.php**

```
<?php    
$errors         = array();      // array to hold validation errors    
$data           = array();      // array to pass back data    
// validate the variable    
if (empty($_POST['name']))    
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';    
// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean of false    
if ( ! empty($errors)) {    
    // if there are items in our errors array, return those errors    
    $data['success'] = false;    
    $data['errors']  = $errors;    
} else {    
    // show a message of success and provide a true success variable    
    $data['success'] = true;    
    $data['message'] = 'Success!';    
}    
// return all our data to an AJAX call    
echo json_encode($data);
```

Any idea why I am getting the internal server error?

Kind regards, Andrew

Comment: It may be the space in `! empty($errors)`

Comment: Many times an error 500 is a syntax error in you PHP code, you should check the server error logs, you can have the reason there.. @KooiInc the space there shouldn't matter (even if a bit ugly)

Comment: It would help if you can show your request params from the network log, Also Try removing  everything from the PHP file and return something plain , this will make sure that the problem is somewhere in your code, then we can debug PHP line by line

Comment: Is you console showing an error ? It could be for CORS policy reasons

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, but still no success.  I'm now running with a minimal PHP file that takes no parameters and just returns a text string.  I managed to find the apache logs (not the Synology PHP logs) and found "[path] not within configured docroot".  But setting doc_root in Web Station PHP settings (core) has no effect.  Any suggestions?